# How to use withCredentials for Perforce in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I am attempting to retrieve the credentials for Perforce in my `Jenkinsfile`. The p4 credentials are saved using the standard Jenkins credentials store. I need the credentials to be in scope so that I can call a utility that will invoke `p4` operations from a utility. The utility expects the `P4PORT` environment variable to be set.

I am aware of `withCredentials`, however, I am not sure how to leverage this to retrieve the `P4Port` property saved on the credential.

The closest credentials binding I've found is `usernamePassword()`, however that doesn't seem to be able to give me access to the `P4Port` property.

The error I am experiencing is:

```
Credentials 'my-credentials-id' is of type 'Perforce Password Credential'...
```

Is there a binding that is intended to be used with `'Perforce Password Credential'`?

Comment: You should first install the **p4** plugin , then when adding credentials choose **Perforce Password Credential** from the **Kind** drop-down select. See the [Full guide](https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/files/guest/perforce_software/p4jenkins/main/README.md?v=17) for more info.

Comment: @NoamHelmer thanks for the reply, unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question. I have the p4 plugin installed, and the Perforce credentials are saved in the credentials manager as a  Perforce Password Credential currently. What I am looking to do is retrieve the those credentials from within a pipeline using `withCredentials`.

Comment: in that case you should use the p4 pipeline steps that the plugin provides - they are build to consume these type of credentials. See more info [Here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/p4-plugin/blob/master/docs/WORKFLOW.md).

Comment: Thanks again for the reply Noam. Unfortunately, I can't simply rely on the pipeline steps provided by the p4 plugin. The utility I am consuming in my pipeline (UnrealAutomationTool) expects to be able to call the `p4` CLI on its own, and as such makes assumptions about certain environment variables being set, which is why I am trying to leverage `withCredentials` to populate those variables.

Comment: Seem it should work using `withCredentials`, check out [JENKINS-58209](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-58209)

Comment: You are correct in that we can retrieve the username and password fields using `usernamePassword`, however the credential type `Perforce Password Credential` contains additional properties which as far as I can tell, cannot be retrieved using `usernamePassword`. For example,  `Perforce Password Credential` also includes the `port`, SSL flag, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The binding to a variable is handled by https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding/

It only supports specific types of credentials, see
https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/credentials/com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/common/package-summary.html

So the credentials plugin would have to have a credential Interface that allows access to additional information, specifically your P4PORT.  Then the p4 plugin could implement it.

The p4 plugin supports the username/password (StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials) with the perforce password credential.